# deprecated "Can't use a hash as a reference" perl error in legacy code

Tags: perl, hash, reference, deprecated

We've got some legacy code throwing up the "Can't use a hash as a reference" perl error.  The previous "fix" was to turn off warnings, but new perl has made the warning a hard error and so now someone's got to actually fix the problem.

The code looks like this...

```
foreach my $a (keys %{$x->{'y'}}) {
        my $b = %$x->{'y'}->{$a};
        <some other stuff>
}
```

My understanding is that something like  %j->{'k'} should be converted into $j{'k'}, but the %$ thing with two pointers is more than I can process, given that I only understand this at the most general of levels.

It seems that only the line within the loop is causing the error, but I included the foreach for reference.

Is it clear what the original author is attempting to do and is there an obvious fix that that will clean this up once and for all?

Thanks.

Comment: The `$x` is a hash _reference_ (judged by its use).  To retrieve a value for a key from it we _dereference_ it, as `$x->{key}`.  Specifically _not as_ `%$x->{}`.  (What worked a long time ago.)  It's only when we want the whole hash when we say `%$x` (like for `keys`).  Here your hash has hashrefs for values thus `keys %$x->{y}` to derefence those into hashes and `$x->{y}->{$a}` to get one value from one of those hashrefs (the `$a` one).

Answer (score 4):

Just dropping the % should do it.  I can't imagine anything else that could have been meant.

Comment: Ha, that was it.  That's what I get for overthinking the punctuation.  Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the idea is to iterate over the entries in the hash referenced by `$x->{'y'}`. The `foreach` loop sets `$a` to each key in turn. The loop body would then assign the corresponding value to `$b`.

From the `keys` expression we can see that `$x` must contain a reference to a hash, and that the value under the key `'y'` must be a reference to another hash. From that you can get the value under `$a` by doing

```
my $b = $x->{'y'}->{$a};
# or: 
my $b = $x->{y}{$a};  # if you don't like typing
```

The problem with your original code is the `%$x->{...}` part. `%$x` dereferences the reference in `$x`, so what you get as a result is an actual hash. The `->{...}` operator then tries to dereference it again, which makes no sense (as the error message says, a hash is not a reference). Just drop the `%` and let `->{...}` do the work.

(Alternatively, if you're feeling crazy, you can do `(\%$x)->{'y'}->{$a}`. In addition to `%` (to dereference the reference in `$x`), we use `\` (to take a reference to the hash we just got), which can then correctly be dereferenced (again) by `->{...}`.)

---

For the future, blindly silencing warnings is usually not a good idea, especially if they tell you about bugs in your code.

Comment: Totally agree on your comment about the warnings, but I am late to this party.  Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: to be fair, this wasn't a bug, exactly.  it was an unintentional feature that made it work in the first place, which was later deprecated and then later removed.  but that makes the point even more strongly: don't ever ignore deprecation warnings; used to be things would stay deprecated forever, but now perl is making an effort to actually remove deprecated things within a reasonable time.